# Is this the correct way to think about the comlplex function $f(z)=\cos(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

When considering complex functions I know that say $f(z)=e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$. So now consider $f(z)=\cos(z).$

My question is :

Following the same logic used for $e^z$ does this the mean that $\cos(z)=\cos(x+iy)=\cos(x)\cos(iy)-\sin(x)\sin(iy)$ (by trig identities) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. I mean, that's not the definition, but it is correct nevertheless. Now, you should add to it that$$\cos(iy)=1+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^4}{4!}+\cdots=\cosh(y)$$and that$$\sin(iy)=iy+i\frac{y^3}{3!}+i\frac{y^5}{5!}+\cdots=i\sinh(y).$$

Comment: Ah this addition to what I was thinking will prove to be very helpful in calculating residues and the like I think . Thank you :) I will accept the answer when it allows me it says I have to wait six minutes

Comment: one more small query , What is the usual definition if mine is not the standard ?

Comment: I think that the most usual one is$$\cos z=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\cdots\text{ and }\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots$$Another possibility is$$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2\text{ and }\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$

Comment: ah yes these look familiar , now that I see them again. thanks.